# Cant access localhost on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I run the server and go to `localhost:3000` I get this error:

> ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished No connection pool with id
>   primary found.

The code in question:

```
activerecord (5.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:874
:in `retrieve_connection'
```

Comment: since it's an ActiveRecord error, the issue is with connecting to the database, not to the localhost. What's in your database.yml file?

Comment: Do you have a database configuration file? Located in config/database.yml

Comment: # SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3

Comment: yes the default one. in tutorials it didn't said something that i must change something in database.yml or etc. what i have to do? :S

Comment: Do you have any installed database on your computer?

Comment: i have just installed sqlite3. (all the official tutorials says was just that , i did step by step everything)

Comment: try `rails dbconsole` to see if you have a working db.

Comment: it normally returns:
SQLite Version 3.6.16

Comment: I have same problem. I can't find the way to solve that :((

Comment: Also have this problem

Comment: `rake db:create` and  `rake db:migrate` if haven't created it before. And showing full gemfile and database.yml could make it much easier to solve it...

Answer (score 0):

I would have commented, but I lack the reputation. Anyway, this error is sometimes caused by the sqlite version. I would suggest removing any version number from the gemfile, i.e.:

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

Then run 'bundle update'.

EDIT:

To be thorough, make sure you've also executed 'rake db:migrate' if you've created any models.

Comment: you mean to remove number 3? to make it gem 'sqlite' just this? if yes , i just tried and and on bundle update it says: could not find gem sqlite x64-mingw32 in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available in this machine.

Comment: No, don't remove the '3' from 'sqlite3'. If there was a version number, (gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3', '>= 1.3.11') delete that. The version number, in this case, is everything following 'sqlite3'.

Comment: it doens't have something . it's just only gem 'sqlite3'

Answer (score 0):

i also faced the same issue. i just uncommented

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

and then restart my rails server