# No connection pool with id primary found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just installed Ruby on Rails v5 but when I run the rails server and go to browser, this error comes up?

```
def retrieve_connection(spec_name) #:nodoc:
    pool = retrieve_connection_pool(spec_name)
    raise ConnectionNotEstablished, "No connection pool with id #{spec_name} found." unless pool
    conn = pool.connection
    raise ConnectionNotEstablished, "No connection for #{spec_name} in connection pool" unless conn
    conn
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38212305/cant-access-localhost-on-ruby-on-rails is a start. I suggest googling the exact errors that you're getting. Likely something common when you first install/run

Comment: Please, send your config/database.yml file

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem myself; one or more of the databases you are using on your database.yml files are  currently not installed.

---

Since you mentioned you "just" installed RoRv5, That Database is most likely sqlite3, make sure u are including **gem 'sqlite3'** on your gemfile then

```
run: gem install sqlite3
```

If you are using a different database, run the corresponding **gem install** command.